# Type-1 VMM and Ring 1

Tags: virtualization, context-switch, protected-mode, hypervisor

Recently, I am doing homework about Virtualization. My question is, how VMM transfer control to the guest kernel and run that code in Ring 1?

Type-1 VMM: This is the classical trap-and-emulate VMM. The VMM runs directly on hardware, acts as a "host operating system" in Ring 0. Guest kernel and guest applications run upon VMM, in Ring 1 and Ring 3 respectively.

1. When Guest applications make a syscall, it will trap to Ring 0 VMM, (CPU is designed to do this).
2. **VMM will then detect that this is a syscall, and then transfer control to the guest kernel syscal handler and execute it in Ring 1.**
3. When it is done, the guest kernel performs syscall-return, this is a privileged call, which will trap again into VMM.
4. VMM then do a real return to the guest user space in ring 3. (CPU is also designed to do this.)

My question is about step 2. **How does the VMM transfer control to guest kernel and force the CPU to ring 1?** It couldn't be a simple "call" since then the guest kernel code will run in ring 0. It must be some kind of "syscall-return" or some special context switch instructions.

Do you have some idea? Thank you!

Comment: Which hypervisor you are talking about? This may differ from one VMM to another.

Comment: @hsalimi Thanks! But actually I don't have a specific VMM. In general, how many approaches are there to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply running the guest OS with a CS selector with RPL=1 (on x86 though). Returning from more privileged ring to lower one is generally done using iret.

Answer (score 0):

Xen is one of the VMMs that run guest OSes in ring 1. In Xen, instructions such as the HLT instruction, (the instruction in ring 1 where the guest OSes run) is replaced by a hyper-call. In this case, instead of calling the HLT instruction, as is done eventually in the Linux kernel, the xen_idle() method is called. It performs a hypercall instead, namely, the HYPERVISOR_sched_op(SCHEDOP_block, 0) hypercall that manages the privilege ring switching. For more info see:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8909